# Ruby - undefined method '<'

Tags: ruby, methods, proc

I'm following a tutorial about how to put a proc to a method.

They asked me the following thing :

"Now we will use the table ages. Create a variable called "young" and assign the result of the call ".select" on "ages", and place your "inf_100" proc argument to filter the ages that are less than 100. Do not forget to convert your proc in  block with the ampersand (&)."

So I did as the following, but I get the following

> error : "undefined method `<' for [23, 101, 7, 104, 11, 94, 100, 121,
>   101, 70, 44]:Array"

I tried a lot of things but I keep getting this mistake, but I can't figure out what's wrong

```
ages = [23, 101, 7, 104, 11, 94, 100, 121, 101, 70, 44]

inf_100 = Proc.new { |i| i.select(&ages<100) } #
```

What they asked me in the previous exercice

```
jeunes = ages.select(&inf_100) #
```

The current exercice

Can someone tell me where I did wrong? Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the previous chapter requires you to write a `Proc` which takes an integer and determine whether it is less than 100.

It should be written like this:

```
inf_100 = Proc.new {|i| i < 100 }
```

Which can be interpreted as:

> inf_100 is assigned with a `Proc` which takes `i` as parameter and returns the result of `i < 100`.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it resolved the question ! But What bothers me is that with  "inf_100 = Proc.new {|i| i < 100 }", you don't say which array you speak about anymore, how do the code knows which array he has to take the number from?

Comment: @Jaeger The proc doesn't care about the array. It processes on a single number. Consider how you will pick all numbers less than 100 from a set: pick up a number from the set every time, **check if the number is less than 100, if it is**, place it in the result set. See, you will check only a number every time. Sometimes we call this a *predicate*. The `select` method takes a predicate, process the elements one by one, and collect all elements that satisfy the predicate as result.